# Join multiple dataframes using join_all from plyr

Tags: r, plyr

I've three data-frames that I would like to join. They don't have the same length and how to join two of them was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792432/compare-frequencies-of-samples-in-r). 
I was trying to use `join_all` from `plyr` but no dress for success as it takes the `'x'` ranging from 2-7 from the `df.a` and by-passes the x values for 1 from `df.b`. I struggle to find the answer in the documentation for [`join_all`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/plyr.pdf#page.28).

MWE:

```
library(plyr)
df.a <- c(5, 4, 5, 7, 3, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3, 6, 5, 6, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 4)
df.b <- c(1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 7, 7, 4, 3, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 5)
df.c <- c(3, 1, 3, 6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, 2, 7, 5, 1)
table(df.a)
count(df.a)
df.a.count <- count(df.a)
df.b.count <- count(df.b)
df.c.count <- count(df.c)

#normalize the data
df.a.count$freq <- sapply(df.a.count$freq, function(X) X/length(df.a))
df.b.count$freq <- sapply(df.b.count$freq, function(X) X/length(df.b))
df.c.count$freq <- sapply(df.c.count$freq, function(X) X/length(df.c))

#solution using merge
df.m <- merge(df.a.count, df.b.count, by ='x', all=TRUE)
df.m <- merge(df.m, df.c.count, by ='x', all=TRUE)[2:4]
names(df.m) <- c('freq.a', 'freq.b','freq.c')

#problem using join_all
dfs <- list(df.a.count, df.b.count, df.c.count) 
df.all <- join_all(dfs, 'x')
```

Comment: Use `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "x", all = TRUE), dfs)`

Comment: As far as I can see the marked duplicate doesn't indicate how this could be achieved using `join_all`. As a conclusion it is not suitable for this particular operation?

Comment: Regarding the problem with `join_all`, i am not sure if it is a bug or not.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Reduce` with `merge` on the `list` of `data.frame`s

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "x", all = TRUE), dfs)
#   x     freq.x     freq.y       freq
#1 1         NA 0.05555556 0.15384615
#2 2 0.03030303 0.05555556 0.07692308
#3 3 0.06060606 0.16666667 0.15384615
#4 4 0.30303030 0.11111111         NA
#5 5 0.39393939 0.11111111 0.15384615
#6 6 0.12121212 0.38888889 0.30769231
#7 7 0.09090909 0.11111111 0.15384615
```